# Cassandra 4.0 nodes fails to restart

Tags: cassandra

Nodes fail after restart with the error:

```
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-12] 2021-08-17 11:09:07,845 InboundConnectionInitiator.java:464 - /X.X.46.68:7000(/X.X.46.68:56090)->/X.X.X.77:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-cdaa1ab9 messaging connection established, version = 12, framing = LZ4, encryption = unencrypted
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] 2021-08-17 11:09:07,867 InboundConnectionInitiator.java:464 - /X.X.86.42:7000(/X.X.86.42:52188)->/X.X.X.77:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-9c2d74c5 messaging connection established, version = 12, framing = CRC, encryption = unencrypted
ERROR [main] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,523 CassandraDaemon.java:909 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1801)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:648)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:934)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:784)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:729)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:420)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:763)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:887)
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,530 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,531 Gossiper.java:1989 - No local state, state is in silent shutdown, or node hasn't joined, not announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,531 MessagingService.java:441 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-7] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,534 OutboundConnection.java:1150 - /X.X.X.77:7000(/X.X.X.77:52766)->/X.X.X.76:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-27a82ea6 successfully connected, version = 12, framing = CRC, encryption = unencrypted
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-8] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,534 OutboundConnection.java:1150 - /X.X.X.77:7000(/X.X.X.77:52768)->/X.X.X.76:7000-LARGE_MESSAGES-762ad3e9 successfully connected, version = 12, framing = CRC, encryption = unencrypted
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,535 OutboundConnection.java:1150 - /X.X.X.77:7000(/X.X.X.77:35938)->/X.X.X.40:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-97e069da successfully connected, version = 12, framing = CRC, encryption = unencrypted
```

Seeds and other nodes show the following in the debug log while the node is starting up:

```
   ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] 2021-08-17 11:09:07,535 OutboundConnection.java:1058 - /X.X.X.116:7000->/X.X.X.77:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-ef747971 channel in potentially inconsistent state after error; closing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum payload size is 128KiB
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.FrameEncoderCrc.encode(FrameEncoderCrc.java:73)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.FrameEncoder.write(FrameEncoder.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1020)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:299)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.AsyncChannelPromise.writeAndFlush(AsyncChannelPromise.java:77)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundConnection$EventLoopDelivery.doRun(OutboundConnection.java:837)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundConnection$Delivery.run(OutboundConnection.java:687)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-10] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,540 InboundConnectionInitiator.java:464 - /X.X.X.77:7000(/X.X.X.77:36684)->/X.X.X.116:7000-SMALL_MESSAGES-8ab4a5dc messaging connection established, version = 12, framing = CRC, encryption = unencrypted
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-11] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,540 InboundConnectionInitiator.java:464 - /X.X.X.77:7000(/X.X.X.77:36686)->/X.X.X.116:7000-LARGE_MESSAGES-7f053d49 messaging connection established, version = 12, framing = CRC, encryption = unencrypted
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] 2021-08-17 11:09:15,680 NoSpamLogger.java:92 - /X.X.X.116:7000->/X.X.X.77:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-[no-channel] failed to connect
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /X.X.X.77:7000
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124)
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:673)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:530)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] 2021-08-17 11:09:45,714 NoSpamLogger.java:92 - /X.X.X.116:7000->/X.X.X.77:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-[no-channel] failed to connect
```

Started happening after upgrading from 3.10 to 4.0. Not a firewall issue or a bad configuration, as the same configuration was working prior.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those are errors so they're not the cause of your nodes failing to restart.

The first entry for gossip is logged at `DEBUG` so it's not an issue. The second entry for messaging is logged at `INFO` level so it's just informational and nothing to be concerned with.

You need to review the `system.log` and pay attention to the last 1 or 2 `ERROR` entries because those are relevant for understanding why the nodes failed to restart. Cheers!

**[EDIT]** This error indicates that there is an issue with contacting the seed nodes:

```
ERROR [main] 2021-08-17 11:09:08,523 CassandraDaemon.java:909 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1801)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:648)
    ...
```

In Cassandra 4.0, nodes are now identified by a combination of their IP + port ([CASSANDRA-7544](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7544)) so make sure that you've configured the seeds list accordingly. For example:

```
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "10.1.2.3:7000,10.1.2.4:7000,10.1.2.5:7000"
```

It's very important that at least one of the seed nodes is up and fully operational. For this reason, it is recommended to upgrade the seed nodes first.

Also ensure that there is network connectivity between nodes using Linux utilities such as `nc` and `telnet`. Check that traffic between nodes on port `7000` is not being blocked by firewalls (for example `iptables` or `firewalld`). If you rebooted the servers, it's quite common for firewalls to be enabled by accident.

**[UPDATE]** Check that the clocks on the servers are in sync. If there is too much drift, nodes will not be able to gossip. Cheers!

Comment: you are right; reason for failure is:
```ERROR [main] 2021-08-17 02:37:51,348 CassandraDaemon.java:909 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
 at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1801)
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:648)
```

My assumption is gossip is failing with all other nodes:

ERROR ...  channel in potentially inconsistent state after error; closing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum payload size is 128KiB

Comment: Can you please edit your original question and post the full error + full stack trace there? Cheers!

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the new info. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately the issue remains after adding the the port num to the seeds 
```
seed_provider:     
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider       parameters:        
   - seeds: "X.X.X.40:7000,X.X.X.46:7000"
``` 
It is also unlikely the firewalls are the cause because there is gossip data flowing between nodes.

Comment: The log entries you posted says otherwise. They can't gossip that's why you're seeing `failed to connect` and `Connection refused` for comms on port `7000`. Cheers!

Comment: Correct, the order of the errors is as follows:

1- gossip from node A to node B -sent and delivered  

2- B throws:

   ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] 2021-08-17 11:09:07,535 OutboundConnection.java:1058 - /X.X.X.116:7000->/X.X.X.77:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-ef747971 channel in potentially inconsistent state after error; closing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum payload size is 128KiB
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.FrameEncoderCrc.encode(FrameEncoderCrc.java:73)

3- 1->2 repeated several times
 
4- eventually A fails to start

5- B throws ConnectException after A is down

Comment: @JadYounan have you got any resolution of the issue ?

Comment: FWIW I've updated my answer to include checking for clock drift on servers which would prevent gossip from working correctly.

Comment: @ErickRamirez in 4.0 I don't think the specifying port in seed value is not mandatory.. by default it will take storage port 7000, Specifying port in seed value becomes relevant when someone running multiple instances of Cassandra on single m/c . Let me know if you agree on this.

Answer (score 0):

The below error message in the question was due to the size of gossip messages sent when a node (re)starts may exceed the hard limit in large cluster.

```
 ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] 2021-08-17 11:09:07,535 OutboundConnection.java:1058 - /X.X.X.116:7000->/X.X.X.77:7000-URGENT_MESSAGES-ef747971 channel in potentially inconsistent state after error; closing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum payload size is 128KiB
```

This is a bug since 4.0-alpha1 and was fixed in 4.0.1. Check [CASSANDRA-16877](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16877).

Also if you see log message like below in one of the seed node, It is due to drift in time clock among node which Erick has mentioned in his updated answer.

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2021-09-10 11:14:26,567 MessagingMetrics.java:206 - GOSSIP_DIGEST_SYN messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 0 internal and 1 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 0 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 15137813 ms
```